# jpages and dynamic content not working

Tags: php, jquery, dynamic-content

This problem is doing my nut. I have jpages plugin configured ok. I'm using it to list jobs on a site. My issue is that i'm using php generated content for the returned results. Some of the content works fine with jpages but as soon as i add my short description field it just stops working.

```
<ul id="itemContainer">
<?php 
  foreach ($search_res as $value) {  
?>
<li>
<div class="searchlongbox">
<h3 id="search-title"><?php echo "Job title:  " . $value['title'];?></h3>
<div id="search-wrap">
<div class="search-salary"><strong>Salary:</strong> &pound;<?php echo $value['salary'];?></div>
<div class="search-location"><strong>Location:</strong> <?php echo $value['region'];?></div>
</div>
<div id="search-description-short">
<?php 
echo limit_text($value['description'], 40);
?>
</div>
<div id="search-added"><strong>Job Added:</strong> 
<?
php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($value['date_added']));
?>
</div>
<?php
$job_id = $value['jobs_id'];
echo "<div class='buttonsleft'><br/><a id='sendmore' class='button'                        href=jobs_details.php?jobId=$job_id>find out more</a>
</div>";
 ?>
</div>
</li>
<?php }?>
</ul>
<!-- navigation holder -->
<div class="holder">
</div>
```

Here's the js

```
/* initiate the plugin */
$("div.holder").jPages({
containerID  : "itemContainer",
perPage      : 5,
startPage    : 1,
startRange   : 1,
midRange     : 5,
endRange     : 1,
callback : function( pages, items ){
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
console.log(items); 
}
});
```

I just don't know why it won't work.

Thanks in advance
Rob

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution to those of you who may have this problem. It's taken me about 2 weeks on and off to fix this!
If you are dynamically creating content for use with this plugin. use php's strip_tags() function. It seems that any html or MSWord(YUK) formatting will prevent this plugin from working correctly solution snippet below.....

```
<div id="search-description-short">
<?php 
echo limit_text(strip_tags($value['description']), 40);
?>
</div>
```

Hope this helps someone. 
Rob